# How many times has a player scored a try on debut?

Tags: trivia, rugby-union

I know Brian Habana scored a try on his debut, but today (June 9th 2018) is the first test I have ever seen were two players scored a try on debut for the same team. How many times have players scored tries on their debut, and is today's test between the Boks and England the first time two players from the same team have done it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the rugby international between England Women and Canada Women held on Friday 17th November 2017, England beat Canada 79 - 5.

Of England's 13 tries, 9 were scored by 3 players who were making their debut.
They were -

- Jess Breach scoring 6 tries
- Abby Dow scoring 2
- Ellie Kildunne scoring 1

Match report [here](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2017/nov/17/england-canada-womens-rugby-union-international).

Answer (score 1):

No. In the [very first rugby international](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1871_Scotland_versus_England_rugby_union_match), three tries were scored and by definition everybody in that match was in their debut match.